# Как передать методу в качестве параметра класс который не известен?

Tags: c#

Хочу реализовать код, который будет принимать в качестве параметра другой класс который будет использовать его для заполнения его данными.

вот код который работает с определенным классом `TickerResponse`,  а я хочу сделать возможным выбирать в какой класс я хочу записать данные.

Вот рабочий код который я хочу модифицировать:

```
public TickerResponse ToObject(string jsonResponse)
{
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TickerResponse>(jsonResponse);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Используйте дженерики:

```
public T ToObject<T>(string jsonResponse)
{
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonResponse);
}
```

При вызове укажите тип:

```
var tickerResponse = ToObject<TickerResponse>(jsonResponse);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое)) Еще есть вопрос, но не обязательный) что означает T ?)

Comment: Это "параметр типа", т.е. как обычный параметр метода, но передаем не значение, а тип. Вместо `T` с таким же успехом можно написать `X` или `OutputType` или любое другое валидное C#-имя (но `T` является общепризнанным здесь). Документация по теме: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-type-parameters

Comment: Спасибо огромное!)